# Analysis Services - cube on different server to source data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas

I'm trying to create an analysis service cube.

The source data for the dimensions etc is coming from tables on a Sql Server 2000 box.

I want to create the cube though on a sql server 2008r2 box.

How do i do this? BIDS seems to want to put the cube in the same place as the data feed? Does that source data have to be on the same server as the cube?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source data can be located anywhere.  The connection string in your data source defines where the data is read from.  Set the deployment server in your project properties to tell BIDS where to deploy the cube to.

Comment: ah I see. I thought that it would be weird to have no way of getting remote data.